# Why doesn't the login module get called on Wildfly with Keycloak?

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak, wildfly-10, undertow

We have a Wildfly 10 AS, and we have the Keycloak 4.1 SAML Adapter installed according to the description in §3.1.2 of the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#jboss-eap-wildfly-adapter-2)

That means, our standalone.xml has

- loaded the org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-adapter-subsystem extension
- added the urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-saml:1.1 subsystem to our server's profile
- defined a security domain (although in our case it's not called keycloak)
- defined org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule as a <login-module> on that domain

Furthermore, we have an Application.war, which

- contains some HTML to deliver
- has a keycloak-saml.xml
- has a jboss-web.xml, configuring the deployment's security-domain to the one defined in standalone.xml
- has a web.xml which sets the auth-method configured to KEYCLOAK-SAML

And yet, the login module never gets called. Why?

Is there any logging we can enable to shed more light?
Any places in undertow, picketlink, or picketbox to set breakpoints?